# Mousein-mouseout flickers when mouse goes over the selected children

Tags: jquery

I want to have mousein and mouseout for the parrent div which is "container"; but when you mouse over the children which are "red" and "black", it flickers(or better to say it applies the events one more time!However I dont want to bind the events one more time whn you go over the children which are red and black divs); How can I solve this ?
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/pTU3L/6/)

**JS:**

```
$('#container').mouseover(function () {
    $('#red').stop(true, true).animate({
        width: '110px'
    }, 200);
})
$('#container').mouseout(function () {
    $('#red').stop(true, true).animate({
        width: '0px'
    }, 200);
})
```

Thanks

Comment: Just a suggestion: 1) You can use jQuery `changing` to improve the performance of your code like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pTU3L/12/) and 2) You can just use the jQuery [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pTU3L/13/). The `.hover()` method binds handlers for both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during the time the mouse is within the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events

Comment: +1 just to expand...`mouseenter` and `mouseleave` do NOT fire when hovering over a parent's child which is exactly what you need